# Database design for application tracking

Tags: database-design, schema

I am new to the world of DB design and was hoping to get some pointers on the design I have been thinking of using. My goal is to track applications that are publicly listed on a website. Every hour, I will get get these applications from the website.

Any application that is listed on the website is an active application. When they become inactive, they get removed from the website. My intent is to scrape the website and compare the applications in the database with those that I just got from the website. Those that are in the scrape, but not the DB will be inserted. Those that are in the DB but not in the scrape, will be marked as "inactive" in the DB.

One more thing I want to do is keep track of application history. I intend on doing this by comparing applications from the scrape to those in the DB. If their titles match, but any of the fields differ, then the application will be updated. The old version will be stored in an `application_history` table. Even if the application gets archived, I do not want to lose the history.

To make this work I was planning on using 4 tables. There will be a master `applications` table that contains all of the active and inactive applications. The applications do not have a unique ID, so I planned on hashing the title to use it as an ID:

```sql
CREATE TABLE applications (
    id VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
    url VARCHAR(255),
    title TEXT,
    summary TEXT,
    proposal TEXT,
    -- more fields...
);
```

The `active_applications` table will just contain the currently active applications (those that come from the scrape):

```sql
CREATE TABLE active_applications (
    id VARCHAR(64),
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES applications(id)
);
```

The `archived_applications` table would look something like this.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE archived_applications (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    application_id VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    archived_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (application_id) REFERENCES applications(id)
);
```

Lastly, there would be the `application_history` table that keeps track of changes in the applications. This one I am not too sure about. Any ideas on the best way to keep track of changes?

```sql
CREATE TABLE application_history (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    application_id VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    changed_data TEXT,
    change_time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (application_id) REFERENCES applications(id)
);
```

Overall I am looking for feedback on if this would be logical. Is this structure conducive to moving values from active to archive?